# How to sort a dictionary by values which are lists using itemgetter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, sorting, dictionary

I have the following dictionary:

```
Dict = {'1': ['Adam', 27], '2': ['Brad', 31], '3': ['Paul', 19]}
```

I would like to sort it by the int value in the list in ascending order. So my desired result is:

```
Desired = {'3': ['Paul', 19], '1': ['Adam', 27], '2': ['Brad', 31]}
```

I'm trying to execute the following:

```
v = sorted(Dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter([1][1]))
```

But it keeps on erroring out with:

```
v = sorted(Dict.items(), key=operator.itemgetter([1][1]))
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Can I not pass the item using multiple dimensions to itemgetter? What am I missing?

Thanks!

Comment: Warning: you can sort the items of a dictionary, but you cannot sort a dictionary as a dictionary has no ordering. Meaning, in your case, `Dict == Desired`. What you indeed sort is `Dict.items()`, which is not exactly a list but pretty much acts like one.

Comment: Also, to explain the error: python interprets `[1][1]` as a list of one element, `1`, from which you are taking the second element, therefore it complains with `IndexError`. This is because `itemgetter` does not have some special syntax, so it doesn't make sense to provide arguments this way.
Finally, there is also the fact that `itemgetter` can only fetch items to a one-level depth, not two like what you want.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification and for adding details on the error. I understand it a lot better now!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `itemgetter` here in this case. Use `lambda`:

```
>>> sorted(Dict.items(), key=lambda x: x[1][1])
[('3', ['Paul', 19]), ('1', ['Adam', 27]), ('2', ['Brad', 31])]
```

> Create my own function where I pass the value from the dictionary

You can but you have to use `Dict.items()`:

```
def my_sort(x):
    return x[1][1]

sorted(Dict.items(), key=my_sort)
# [('3', ['Paul', 19]), ('1', ['Adam', 27]), ('2', ['Brad', 31])]
```

Comment: Thanks! Just for my understanding is there a way I could do it without using lambda functions? Maybe create my own function where I pass the value from the dictionary and that returns the 1st element which then becomes my key?